# Proper Speaking

Tags: sintaxis

Hey does anyone know how to make sure sentences are proper in Spanish? I am in a high school Spanish class, but whenever I speak it comes out improper (Kind of like mixing up the words on accident). Does anyone else know if there is a way to know if it is not grammatically correct by looking at it?

For example (When saying): "John is coming." in Spanish, one I never know proper translator apps/websites, and also sometimes I see: "John is coming today." and the today part (hoy) is in the front.

Another confusion, for example, is when saying "with me" I know is *conmigo* but when the "with" isn't there, like saying: "The teacher failed me".

What do you do? Does anyone have a list of rules, or notes on making proper and not messed up sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news: there is a "method to the madness"; you can google/bing something like "Spanish sentence structure" and find pages like [this](http://www.spanish411.net/Spanish-Sentence-Structure.asp)

Going down that path, though, means a lot of brain-numbing rote drilling and memorization. I prefer to "learn it by ear" - eventually, you'll be able to tell what is right by if it sounds right.

The bad news: I've been trying to learn Spanish for three years, and I still get word order jumbled up on a regular basis. But I can speak English with no problem, because it is my native tongue, and...I never learned the rules of English sentence structure, I learned it "by ear."

Which tack you decide to take (following rules or following your ear (or some combination of the two)) is a personal choice  and is somewhat like learning music - you can either play the notes on the page, painstakingly, or you can play by ear. Which is better probably differs from person to person.